# Finding whether a number is prime or not python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code to find out if a number is prime or composite.
The code works fine when I input a prime number but when I input a composite number the output is:

```
enter number: 100
The number is not prime.
The number is prime.
```

I don't want `The number is prime` output for composite number input.
Here is my code:

```
print ('This program tells whether the number is prime or not')
print ('')

def prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    print('The number is not prime.')
  else:
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
      if x % n == 0:
        print('The number is not prime.')
        break
    print('The number is prime.')

i = input('enter number: ')
prime(int(i))
```

Please tell me what can I do to correct it.

Comment: 'break' statement will take you out of the loop, not out of the function. So, whenever you 'break' statement runs you go out of the loop running the commands following the loop. So your other print statement also gets executed. So you should add return Statement or add some variable to check the condition for the other print statement. Moreover, you should maintain your loop range till (x/2), you can find regarding this more on wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why. you are missing else after if. try this:

```
print ('This program tells whether the number is prime or not')
print ('')

def prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    print('The number is not prime.')
  else:
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
      if x % n == 0:
        print('The number is not prime.')
        break
    else:
        print('The number is prime.')

i = input('enter number: ')
prime(int(i))
```

Comment: else should be out of if loop. 117  is working fine.                                                   
This program tells whether the number is prime or not

enter number: 117
The number is not prime.
In [ ]:

Comment: when break is used in if condition, it will come out of the loop when if condition is satisfied and executes next block of statement/s

Comment: @U10-Forward, please try 2,3 with your, it doesn't print any. you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the indentation, you've to move the indentation of the last line and add a `break` after that, so try using:

```
print ('This program tells whether the number is prime or not')
print ('')

def prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    print('The number is not prime.')
  else:
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
      if x % n == 0:
        print('The number is not prime.')
        break
      print('The number is prime.')
      break

i = input('enter number: ')
prime(int(i))
```

Comment: Yes, this works but it does not give any output for values 2 and 3. So can you fix that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if num > 1:
   for n in range(2, x-1):
      if x % n == 0:
         print('The number is not prime.')
         break
   else:
      print('The number is prime.')
else:
    print('The number is not prime.')
```

Simply fix that indentation in the for loop. Also, this looks a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended way to solve this problem.
do not use hard coded print statement.
try to return `True` or `False` instead.

```
def is_prime(x:str):
  if x < 2:
      return False
  else:
      for n in range(2, int(x/2)): # Use this for more speed
          if x % n == 0:
              return False
      return True
```

Now you can check the number is prime or not by calling this `is_prime` function

```
print('Number is prime' if is_prime(6) else 'Number is not prime')
```

Comment: With this you can do whatever you want to the Boolean variable. With condition you can print whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you break the loop the last print statement is called. If you end the function using `return` statement you will not reach the last print statement.

```
def prime(x):
  if x < 2:
      print('The number is not prime.')
  else:
      for n in range(2, x - 1):
          if x % n == 0:
            print('The number is not prime.')
            return
      print('The number is prime.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def prime(x):
  is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, x):
      if x % i == 0:
        is_prime = False
  if is_prime:
    print("It's a prime number.")
  else:
    print("It's not a prime number.")   


n = int(input()) # Check this number
prime_(number=n)
```